# Fourier Transform Syntax and Conventions Clarification

Tags: fourier-transform, convention

One common definition of a fourier transform for function f(x) is
$$F(v)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)e^{2\pi i\tau v}d\tau$$
I know some definitions have an extra sqrt(2*pi). I shall ignore that.

However, there are 3 tau's in the formula and it does not specify how each one relates to x. For example it does not explain for the fourier transform of f(x+1), whether tau+1 replaces all the taus or only for some.

From looking at derivations of fourier transform properties I believe that you must state state both the function and the variable the fourier transform is of. However, if your function is say f((y-1)) convention assumes that the variable is y instead of say (y-1).

1. Is that right?
2. If so, is this the correct fourier transform for f(g(x)) with respect to x?
   $$F(v)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(g(\tau))e^{2\pi i \tau v}d\tau$$

Comment: take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions

Comment: @alexjo Yes, I am aware of those conventions. However, all those conventions are defined for f(x). Not for f(x+1) or f(g(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is
$$
\mathcal F\{f(x)\}=F(\nu)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm e^{-2\pi i x \nu}\,\mathrm d x
$$
With this convention, the inverse Fourier transform is
$$
\mathcal F^{-1}\{F(\nu)\}=f(f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\nu)\,\mathrm e^{+2\pi i x \nu}\,\mathrm d \nu
$$
For $f(x+1)$ we have (time shift property)
$$
\mathcal F\{f(x+1)\}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+1)\,\mathrm e^{-2\pi i (x+1) \nu}\,\mathrm d x=F(\nu)\,\mathrm e^{+2\pi i \nu}
$$
For $f(g(x))=h(x)$ we have to evaluate
$$
\mathcal F\{f(g(x))\})=\mathcal F\{h(x)\}=H(\nu)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(g(x))\,\mathrm e^{-2\pi i x\nu}\,\mathrm d x
$$
There is no genral rule in this case. If $g$ is a bijection and smooth enough then, if integral exists
$$
\mathcal F\{f(g(x))\}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(g(x))\,\mathrm e^{-2\pi i x\nu}\,\mathrm d x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)\,\mathrm e^{-2\pi i g^{-1}(y)\nu}\frac{1}{|g'(y)|}\,\mathrm d y
$$

Comment: You answered question 2 but not did not directly answer question 1. However, judging by your answer I shall assume you answered yes to question 1.